# Can't use useContext in getStaticPaths NextJS Function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-context

Nextjs throws an error: **Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

Whenever I try to access `useContext` Value in `getStaticPaths()` function.

Here's my code:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const { videos } = useVideos();

  const paths = videos.map((video: any) => {
    return {
      params: { id: video.videoId },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

Comment: You can't use hooks inside `getStaticPaths` as it's just a regular function - [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) can only be used in React function components and/or other React hooks.